# btn not getting vertically aligned in the middle

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center the button vertically but doesn't seem to take effect with whatever I have tried

setting the div element to  display: inline-block; and the label element that contain the input element to text-align : center. Also tried applying vertical-align:middle to the div and label.

[image]

html

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header panel-heading">
        <span style="font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold; ">Firm Details</span>
        <div class="pull-right" style="padding-right:10px; display: inline-block;">
            <label style="text-align: center; vertical-align:middle" class="btn btn-primary" [ngClass]="{'btn-primary': EditMode, 'btn-default': !EditMode }"><input  
                    type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="EditMode" class="hidden">Edit Mode</label>

        </div>
    </div>
```

css

```
.btn-primary {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #ee6e0b;
  border-color: #d6630a;
}

.btn-primary:focus,
.btn-primary.focus {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #bd5809;
  border-color: #5c2a04;
}

.btn-primary:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #bd5809;
  border-color: #9b4807;
}

.btn-primary:active,
.btn-primary.active,
.open > .btn-primary.dropdown-toggle {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #bd5809;
  border-color: #9b4807;
}

.btn-primary:active:hover,
.btn-primary:active:focus,
.btn-primary:active.focus,
.btn-primary.active:hover,
.btn-primary.active:focus,
.btn-primary.active.focus,
.open > .btn-primary.dropdown-toggle:hover,
.open > .btn-primary.dropdown-toggle:focus,
.open > .btn-primary.dropdown-toggle.focus {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #9b4807;
  border-color: #5c2a04;
}
```

Applying flex

[image]

Without flex

[image]

Comment: It will be tough to tell you what the problem is without inspecting in the dev console. If you are using bootstrap you can get samples of what you are using. Can you provide anything else.

Comment: You don't need to use `vertical-align:middle` if you are using bootstrap 4, because there it is already in `.btn` class.

Comment: @adil the post 'pull-right' class are used it's not bootstrap 4 it's lower version bootstrap 4

Comment: Best option is to use ,display flex , Justify-content:space-between , align-items:center

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can try this code here:**

your code contains a floating element, the element effect on the parent height, that means a floating element not expand parent height, So, when you give a element floadt right or left then the parent use a clear both or bootstrap use clearfix class.

It easily solves to use flexbox here my code edit form your code:

```css
.panel-heading {
  background: orange;
  overflow: hidden;
  /*display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;*/
   padding-top: 5px !important;
    padding-bottom: 5px  !important;
}
.panel-heading .left-label {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
.btn-primary {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #ee6e0b;
  border-color: #d6630a;
}

.btn-primary:focus,
.btn-primary.focus {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #bd5809;
  border-color: #5c2a04;
}

.btn-primary:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #bd5809;
  border-color: #9b4807;
}

.btn-primary:active,
.btn-primary.active,
.open > .btn-primary.dropdown-toggle {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #bd5809;
  border-color: #9b4807;
}

.btn-primary:active:hover,
.btn-primary:active:focus,
.btn-primary:active.focus,
.btn-primary.active:hover,
.btn-primary.active:focus,
.btn-primary.active.focus,
.open > .btn-primary.dropdown-toggle:hover,
.open > .btn-primary.dropdown-toggle:focus,
.open > .btn-primary.dropdown-toggle.focus {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #9b4807;
  border-color: #5c2a04;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header panel-heading" >
        <span class="left-label" style="font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold; ">Firm Details</span>
        <div class="pull-right" style="padding-right:10px; display: inline-block; vertical-align:middle">
            <label style="text-align: center; vertical-align:middle" class="btn btn-primary" [ngClass]="{'btn-primary': EditMode, 'btn-default': !EditMode }">
            <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="EditMode" class="hidden">Edit Mode</label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please explain the purpose or difference with this code so that it provides an answer.

Comment: I had display:flex earlier and though it centers it , it increases the height of the panel which i don't want.

Comment: @tom also, you learn more about flexbox https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: actually, your element panel-heading contain padding top and bottom both 10px padding.  so your button height and panel 10+10 =20px is the actual height. it's not expanded or not extra height.

Comment: Why is it that when i comment display:flex; , it reduces the height. I mean  I didn't want that extra height.

Comment: @tom your panel-header height = won top and bottom 20px and button height; if you needed to a tiny small button or small button then your problem fix poperly

Comment: Probably I am not understanding your well enough. Not sure where you are getting the calculation of 10 px for button and 10 px for panel. The padding that i have applied is only for the right. I have uploaded screenshots to show the difference between flex and without flex

Comment: I tried this and it seems to remove the height with the flex option on     .card-header {
        padding-top: 5px;
        padding-bottom: 0px;
    }
It this fine

Comment: @tom you can please see code again, I have edited it.